# Problem dry fields- urban areas on supervised classification in QGIS, Landsat 7

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, classification, landsat-7

I am trying to make a supervised classification on a Landsat 7 image using the QGIS 3.16.1 version. I am using the SCP plugin to do then classification.  I am doing the classification using the RGB band 4-3-2 and the maximum likelihood classification.The problem I have is that in the final product the bare or dry fields appear like urban areas. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: This is a very common problem. Why not use the additional bands available with Landsat data?

Comment: So I should select the sample for urban areas with the 4-3-2 band and agricultural areas with 6-5-2  maybe ?
Do you have something else to suggest me or is there any other  way to fix it?

Comment: Use all of the available bands for your classification. You may also want to consider incorporating indices such as NDVI, NDBI, and NDWI.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues you need to address to improve the accuracy of your land cover classification.

1. Make sure you have a large enough sample of training data and that your training data is distributed equally among all of your classes. A good rule of thumb is to use at least 50 samples for each class for areas <1 million acres and fewer than  12 classes (Congalton, 1988)
2. Use all of the available bands for your particular sensor. If you are using Landsat 7, certainly incorporate bands 1-5 and 7.
3. Also include indices such as NDVI, EVI, NDBI, and NDWI. More details [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/indices-gallery.htm). These will help to further differentiate classes.
4. Consider incorporating a non-parametric decision tree classifier such as Random Forests.

Reference:

[Congalton, R. G. (1988). A comparison of sampling schemes used in generating error matrices for assessing the accuracy of maps generated from remotely sensed data. Photogrammetric engineering and remote sensing (USA).](https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/pers/1988journal/may/1988_may_593-600.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much I will check it